# How can I stage a LOT of data, wait, and then run tests in Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, junit4

We have messages coming in from assets and these messages must go through an up to 1 minute process before the data lands where it can be tested.  We have 1200 tests so you can imagine how long it takes.

Currently we are using JUnit 4 and use a "@BeforeClass" method in a runner to find all the methods with the annotation "@Stager" and run them.  Then we wait, then we run the tests.  Works great (so far).

We would like to use Cucumber, however, we need it to:

1. Stage data.
2. Wait for 1 or 2 minutes
3. Run the tests.

**Is there a way to run ALL the "Given" methods first, pause for 1 minute, and then run the tests?**

We have experimented with Parallel threads in Surefire, but it seems buggy and we have 1200 tests.  Frankly, there is too much going on for that.
We don't really need parallel running.  The staged data runs fast, and the tests run fast.  It is the pause between for every test that is a show stopper.

We would consider extending Cucumber.  Maybe:

```
@RunWith(CucumberStage.class)
```

**Is there anything out there that does this?  Any advice?**

Comment: How the data in your current solution are used in the test classes? Could you provide a small snippet which explains your current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u are using maven to run the tests.

If u are planning to use junit runner of cucumber u could continue to use the existing logic to setup the data in the `BeforeClass` of the runner. Easier if u have one runner else u will need to setup up execution order in the plugin. Regarding skipping Given methods u can add a property to the `surefire or failsafe plugin` and use that in the Given method.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>                 
            <systemProperties>
                <property>
                    <name>skipproperty</name>
                    <value>myvaluetest</value>
                </property>
            </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In a Given method u can use this property as a flag to skip the step. Though it is a bit of a hack as it is to be copied to all setup methods. But this way u can still keep the logic inside the given method. And also if u remove the property in POM, cucumber will do the setup the normal way.

```
if(System.getProperty("skipproperty")!=null)
    return;
```

But if u also want to try with TestNg you can use the maven `exec plugin` to run the setup code. This will make it independent of the testing framework. The setup remains the same as above just the exec plugin is added in the POM.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>my-execution</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
               <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
            <mainClass>runner.ExecuteSetup</mainClass>
            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`ExecuteSetup main()` method will contain the existing logic of calling the setup code. Make sure u add the `classpathscope` else u will get a weird `classnotfoundexception`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can only run All Given steps in Cucumber and THEN run rest of the steps. Cucumber will run all steps one by one.